# What did Tara Westover mean by comparing her childhood family accident with "choices coalescing into sediment"?

Tags: meaning, tara-westover, educated

What was Tara Westover trying to imply when she compared the accident her family suffered in her childhood with this?

> Choices, numberless as grains of sand, had layered and compressed, coalescing into sediment, then into rock, until all was set in stone.

(see [here](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Educated/OusUEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Choices,+numberless+as+grains+of+sand,+had+layered+and+compressed,+coalescing+into+sediment,+then+into+rock,+until+all+was+set+in+stone.&pg=PT45&printsec=frontcover))

The quote is from [*Educated*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/35133922-educated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

She is describing the accumulation of choices, imagined as little bits of sediment, that layer upon one another to create something definite and predetermined: the accident imagined as a formation of sedimentary stone.